# Codename one:app size getting increased after installed

Tags: codenameone

I have installed app in Android.Initially when I downloaded app it's size was 5mb after installation it  get increased up to 28 MB and it will getting increased after using.whats reasons behind this? Can you please help me to resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this build hint:

android.allowBackup=false

Android's new behavior is to keep cache. Maybe that's the reason...

Comment: I would also add that an APK is a zip containing DEX code (Androids version of bytecode) on install ART compiles the DEX to native device code and since ARM code is much larger than bytecode/DEX and is no longer zipped you would see a size difference. This is the native OS behavior and you would see it for native apps too